# Application to a list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list of values.

```
{{140, 20}, {140, 15}, {175, 60}, {160, 40}, {175, 60}, {125, 20},
{120, 20}, {105, 5}, {15, 85}, {90, 5}, {150, 35}, {175, 75}, {85,
25}}
```

I want to say that if the first value of the pair is greater than x then add to x to the second value of the pair. Then repeat for the remaining pairs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If

```
lst = {{140, 20}, {140, 15}, {175, 60}, {160, 40}, {175, 60}, {125, 20},
       {120, 20}, {105, 5}, {15, 85}, {90, 5}, {150, 35}, {175, 75}, {85, 25}};
```

then

```
With[{x = 100}, If[#1 > x, {#1, #2 + x}, {#1, #2}] & @@@ lst]
With[{x = 100}, lst /. {a_ /; a > x, y_} :> {a, x + y}]
```

both yield

```
(* {{140, 120}, {140, 115}, {175, 160}, {160, 140}, {175, 160}, {125, 120},
    {120, 120}, {105, 105}, {15, 85}, {90, 5}, {150, 135}, {175, 175}, {85, 25}} *)
```

Answer (score 13):

With in-place modification.  Make a copy of your data and operate on that if desired.

```
dat = {{140, 20}, {140, 15}, {175, 60}, {160, 40}, {175, 60}, {125, 20}, {120, 
   20}, {105, 5}, {15, 85}, {90, 5}, {150, 35}, {175, 75}, {85, 25}};

x = 100;

dat[[All, 2]] += x * UnitStep[dat[[All, 1]] - x];

dat
```

> ```
> {{140, 120}, {140, 115}, {175, 160}, {160, 140}, {175, 160}, {125, 120},
>  {120, 120}, {105, 105}, {15, 85}, {90, 5}, {150, 135}, {175, 175}, {85, 25}}
> ```

Or a one-line function without in-place modificaton:

```
{#, #2 + x*UnitStep[# - x]}\[Transpose] & @@ (dat\[Transpose])
```

Both methods above use vectorization for efficiency.  If brevity is more important you can drop the `Transpose` steps:

```
{#, #2 + x*UnitStep[# - x]} & @@@ dat
```

Or just use `If` as already shown by march and anderstood, but here slightly more tersely:

```
{#, #2 + If[# > x, x, 0]} & @@@ dat
```

Answer (score 8):

Define a function for one list:

```
f[{a_,b_},x_]:=If[a>x, {a,b+x}, {a,b}]
```

Then apply `f` to your list:

```
f[#,x]&/@ {{140, 20}, {140, 15}, {175, 60}, {160, 40}, {175, 60}, {125, 20},
{120, 20}, {105, 5}, {15, 85}, {90, 5}, {150, 35}, {175, 75}, {85,
25}}
(* with x=100: {{140, 120}, {140, 115}, {175, 160}, {160, 140}, {175, 160}, {125, 
 120}, {120, 120}, {105, 105}, {15, 85}, {90, 5}, {150, 135}, {175, 
175}, {85, 25}} *)
```

Possibly cleaner application with a SubValues definition:

```
f[x_][{a_,b_}] := If[a>x, {a,b+x}, {a,b}]

f[100] /@ list
```

Comment: I added a method to your answer.  If you do not like it just revert the edit to remove it.

Answer (score 6):

with x = 100

```
Transpose[{#[[All, 1]], Clip[#[[All, 1]] , {100, 100}, {0, 100}] + #[[All, 2]]}] &@lst
```

> {{140, 120}, {140, 115}, {175, 160}, {160, 140}, {175, 160}, {125, 
>     120}, {120, 120}, {105, 105}, {15, 85}, {90, 5}, {150, 135}, {175, 
>     175}, {85, 25}}

Answer (score 1):

**Using `Position` and `MapAt`:**

```
x = 100;
alist = {{140, 20}, {140, 15}, {175, 60}, {160, 40}, {175, 60}, {125, 
   20}, {120, 20}, {105, 5}, {15, 85}, {90, 5}, {150, 35}, {175, 
   75}, {85, 25}}
pos = Position[alist[[All, 1]], _?(# > x &)]
MapAt[# + {0, 100} &, alist, pos]
```

> {{140, 120}, {140, 115}, {175, 160}, {160, 140}, {175, 160}, {125,
> 120}, {120, 120}, {105, 105}, {15, 85}, {90, 5}, {150, 135}, {175,
> 175}, {85, 25}}